# Parallel.For gives index outside bounds of the array in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this chunk of code:

```
noObjs = 0
Dim oName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tripleIndex As Integer = 0
Do While sr.Peek() <> -1
   readCSV = sr.ReadLine.Split(sepChar(0))
   If readCSV.Length >= 3 Then
       oName = readCSV(0)
       For i = noObjs - 1 To 0 Step -1
           If oName = objNames(i) Then
               obIndOfTriple(tripleIndex) = i
               Exit For
           End If
       Next i
       If i = -1 Then
           objNames(noObjs) = oName
           obIndOfTriple(tripleIndex) = noObjs
           noObjs += 1
       End If
   End If
   tripleIndex += 1
Loop
sr.Close()
```

And I'm trying to parallelise as such:

```
noObjs = 0
Dim oName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tripleIndex As Integer = 0
Dim allData() As String = File.ReadAllLines(in_file)
Parallel.For(0, allData.Count, Sub(k)
                               readCSV = allData(k).Split(sepChar(0))
                               If readCSV.Length >= 3 Then
                                   oName = readCSV(0)
                                   For i = noObjs - 1 To 0 Step -1
                                       If oName = objNames(i) Then
                                           obIndOfTriple(tripleIndex) = i
                                           Exit For
                                       End If
                                   Next i
                                   If i = -1 Then
                                       objNames(noObjs) = oName
                                       obIndOfTriple(tripleIndex) = noObjs
                                       noObjs += 1
                                   End If
                               End If
                               tripleIndex += 1
                               End Sub)
```

However, I get an "index was outside the bounds of the array" at:

```
If oName = objNames(i) Then
```

I should also mention here that objNames() and obIndOfTriple() are declared globally (with a fixed size).
From some searching around, I understand that this has to do with thread safety, although I'm still a newbie in parallelism. 
Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you have multiple threads accessing shared resources without synchronizing access to those resources and thereby introducing a race condition.

For instance, consider `noObjs` in relation to `objNames`. I suspect you want `noObjs` to always reflect the number of actual items in `objNames`.  Now suppose you have two threads that reach `objNames(noObjs) = oName` at the same time, and that `noObjs` is 4 at the time.  One thread will write a value into `objNames(4)` and then the other thread will immediately overwrite it.  The first thread hasn't gotten to the line to increment `noObjs` yet!  Additionally, when both threads do execute `noObjs += 1`, `noObjs` will be 6, but you will have nothing stored in `noObjs(5)`.  That's not the exact case of the exception you're seeing, but it's another symptom of the fragility of the implementation.

In the code that each thread executes, you want to make sure that each thread has its own variable space to work with.  You *could* do that by having `objNames` and `objIndOfTriple` be two dimensional arrays.  The first dimension would be the loop iteration, `k`, and the second would be the index into the array just for that iteration.  Likewise, `noObjs` would be an array, and `noObjs(k)` would be the number of elements in the `objNames` array associated with loop index `k`.

Technically that should work, but then you will need to coalesce `objNames` from a bunch of small arrays into a single large one following the execution of `Parallel.For` - essentially completing the implementation of a map-reduce pattern.

If you do get all that implemented, you might want to take a look at the performance.  You're parallelizing the processing for a single line of input and from the code it doesn't appear you're doing much work for each line. In other words, parallelizing it as you have it, line by line, may actually add more overhead than if you'd just done it sequentially.  If you have 1000 lines, you're essentially asking for 1000 tiny tasks to run at the same time, so managing the tasks becomes more work than actually executing them.  Now, the TPL may decide whether or not to really do something in parallel based on what it thinks is best so that could mitigate the performance hit.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was suspecting that running in e.g. 1000 lines would cause an overhead when compared to a serial implementation. The issue is that noObjs can be 1000 in one case, and 1000000 in another case. To compensate for that, I was thinking of a serial implementation if noObjs <= 100000 for example, and a parallel one for anything higher. Unfortunately, parallelism (in general and in .NET) is a whole new chapter for me.

Comment: actually as the number of lines goes up the problem gets worse because you're now context switching even more objects, each of which isn't doing a lot of work.  You can only truly parallelize to the number of CPUs you have. Experiment perhaps with each parallel task actually being capable of multiple lines... so if you have 1000 maybe each gets 250 lines to do.  Again the framework has some smarts to determine when it's too expensive to parallelize, but I'm not sure what/when it's triggered.

Comment: btw what would you suggest as an optimization for the serial implementation i have posted?

Comment: can't quite figure out what the code is doing, but the first question I guess is "does it need to be optimized"?  If you are seeing it being slow, are you using the profiler to pinpoint what is slow and work on that?  I think you might come up with a LINQ statement to replace your FOR loop, but not sure how it would fare performance-wise.

Comment: just for the records, it's an algorithm that parses files where each row is consisted of "object,attribute,attribute value" (pretty similar to the subject-predicate-object triples of RDF) to find distinct object, distinct attributes, and distinct attribute values for each attribute

Answer (score 3):

Appears you are looking for unique strings.

Rather than a brute force

```
For i = noObjs - 1 To 0 Step -1
   If oName = objNames(i) Then
   obIndOfTriple(tripleIndex) = i
Exit For
```

Try

```
Dictionary<String,Int32>
```

and ContainsKey

Dictionary has fast lookup

[This page has an example of locking in parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx).  But not sure it is the type of lock you need.

Comment: hi Blam, I've implemented your solution, the performance has improved from ~30 secs (with some files i have) to milliseconds. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: 30 seconds to milliseconds and not even worth a +1

Comment: it says my reputation is too low :)